# R not using entire RAM Available

Tags: r, ram

I have a 16GB RAM Machine with windows 64 bit.If I run a model in R it uses only 2GB and remaining memory is free.
I have run the same model in a 4GB machine which takes 4 hours to give the result,So I upgraded to 16GB RAM ,but still then R takes the same 4 hours to run the same model in 16GB machine also.R is not using more than 2GB of RAM.

Any idea why R is not using the entire RAM avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

On a 64-bit OS, handling 16 GB of RAM should be no problem for R.
It is probably a configuration-issue that prevents R from doing so.

You can check the current memory-limit by calling `memory.limit()` (see http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/memory.size).
You can also use `memory.limit(12000)` to set a new limit.

But you should check whether RAM is really the limiting factor. If you are doing some number-crunching, increasing RAM will not speed up the calculation of the result.

Comment: I have checked with memory.limit().It shows entire 16 GB .I am running a randomForest model